# Calculus logarithm function

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I was reading a Calculus Book. In the chapter of Logarithm function I found this exercise but I was not able to complete it myself so I came to you:

Prove that for any $x,y>0$ it is true that   $$ {1\over x} + {1\over y} \ge {4\over {x+y}}$$

Use the inequality to prove that if $a,b,c>1$ then it is true that
$$ \log_a(bc) + \log_b(ca) + \log_c(ab) \ge 4[\log_{bc}(a) + \log_{ca}(b) + \log_{ab}(c)]$$

Comment: Start with $(x-y)^2\ge 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: it is equivalent to $$\frac{x+y}{xy}\geq \frac{4}{x+y}$$
or $$(x+y)^2\geq 4xy$$
or
$$(x-y)^2\geq 0$$
and your second one is equivalent to
$$\log_{a}{bc}+\log_{b}{ca}+\log_{c}{ab}\geq 4\left(\frac{1}{\log_{a}{bc}}+\frac{1}{\log_{b}{ca}}+\frac{1}{\log_{c}{ab}}\right)$$

Comment: Ahh ok, then we know that $\log_a bc=\log_a b + \log_a c$  since $a,b,c>1$ then each one is >0 so i can use the inequality for each one right? wait but I need  (x+y)/xy

Comment: thanks i got it  $\log_ax={\log x\over \log a}$

Comment: Nice that i could help you!

Comment: I got a little mixed up, how can I prove the second inequality?

Comment: You must use that $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\geq \frac{9}{x+y+z}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y>0$ this means that $x+y>0$ and $xy>0$ as well. Look at the given inequality

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$

$$\frac{x+y}{xy} \ge \frac{4}{x+y}$$

$$(x+y)^2 \ge 4xy$$

Continue to prove this equation, which is identical to the given one for the conditions you have stated.

Comment: your last inequality Can be simplified to $$(x-y)^2\geq 0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes indeed it can be. I did not want to spoonfeed the answer to the OP, so I tried to give a hint-like answer to the OP (comply with homework policy)

Comment: ok i thought so!